# Using class member variables that hold functions in definition of inner structures that will be used as template arguments of an unordered_map object

Tags: c++, class, struct, key, unordered-map

I am implementing an object that makes use of `unordered_map`. The object is to be generic, so templates everywhere. In particular the `operator==` and `operator()` are wrapped into structures that are used by the `unordered_map` to respectively check if keys are equal and to generate hash values for keys. I'd like the user to write their own functions that implement the above two operators and pass those methods as input to the class object. The structs would then use those objects. I'm having some trouble with scopes and can't seem to figure out how to do it. Here's my code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template <typename O>
class aClass
{
public:
    aClass( bool        (usrIsEq)(O, O) , 
            std::size_t (usrHashFtn)(O) ) 
    {
        this->usrIsEq    = usrIsEq;
        this->usrHashFtn = usrHashFtn;
    }

    void add(O k, std::string v)
    {
        iTable[ {k} ] = v;
    }

    std::string get(O k)
    {
        return iTable[ {k} ];
    }


private:
    bool        (*usrIsEq)(O, O);
    std::size_t (*usrHashFtn)(O);

    struct Key
    {
        O obj;

        bool operator==(const Key &other)    const
        {
            std::cout <<  "obj " <<   obj << std::endl;
            return usrIsEq(obj, other.obj);
        }
    };

    struct KeyHasher
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Key &k) const
        {
            return usrHashFtn(k);
        }
    };  
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::string, KeyHasher> iTable;

};

bool isEqInts(int a, int b)
{
    return a == b;
}

std::size_t intHashFtn(int x)
{
    std::hash<int> hf;
    return  hf(x);
}

int main()
{
    aClass<int> x(isEqInts, intHashFtn);
    x.add( 1, std::string("hello") );
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to implement the `struct`s `Key` and `KeyHasher` so that they use the functions contained inside the class. The only thing I truly care about is that the functions are given as input to the class constructor. Everything else can be scrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that's tripping you up is that `Key` has no knowledge `usrIsEq` and `KeyHasher` has no knowledge of `usrHashFtn`. You need to pass a pointer or reference to an object of `aClass` to those classes.

Here' one suggestion:

```
struct Key
{
    O obj;
    aClass* ac;

    bool operator==(const Key &other)    const
    {
        std::cout <<  "obj " <<   obj << std::endl;
        return ac->usrIsEq(obj, other.obj);
    }
};

struct KeyHasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(const Key &k) const
    {
        return k.ac->usrHashFtn(k.obj);
    }
};
```

and update the places where you use `Key` to access the table:

```
void add(O k, std::string v)
{
    iTable[{k, this}] = v;
}

std::string get(O k)
{
    return iTable[{k, this}];
}
```

Comment: Hey thinks for the response. I tried something very similar before except that I also had a point to `aClass` in `KeyHasher` as well. That didn't work out too well because `KeyHasher` is only used by `unordered_map` Works well now, you get this one.